# How to add the Bullet physics library to a c++ program

Tags: c++, compilation, bullet

I have compiled the library from https://github.com/bulletphysics/bullet3 and tested some of the examples, but I can't seem to compile this simple program.

```
#include <btBulletDynamicsCommon.h>

int main(){
}
```

I noticed that header file was located in the build_cmake/src directory, so I included it with -I, which worked, but then I had linking errors, so I found the .so files and linked them with the -L option and some globs which removed the linking errors, but I still had warnings. The following command gave me an executable:

```
g++ -Wall main.cpp -I bullet3/src/ -L bullet3/build_cmake/src/*/*.so
```

but had the following warnings:

```
In file included from bullet3/src/btBulletDynamicsCommon.h:38:0,
                 from main.cpp:3:
bullet3/src/BulletDynamics/ConstraintSolver/btSequentialImpulseConstraintSolver.h: In constructor ‘btSISolverSingleIterationData::btSISolverSingleIterationData(btAlignedObjectArray<btSolverBody>&, btConstraintArray&, btConstraintArray&, btConstraintArray&, btConstraintArray&, btAlignedObjectArray<int>&, btAlignedObjectArray<int>&, btAlignedObjectArray<int>&, btAlignedObjectArray<btTypedConstraint::btConstraintInfo1>&, btScalar (*&)(btSolverBody&, btSolverBody&, const btSolverConstraint&), btScalar (*&)(btSolverBody&, btSolverBody&, const btSolverConstraint&), btScalar (*&)(btSolverBody&, btSolverBody&, const btSolverConstraint&), btAlignedObjectArray<int>&, long unsigned int&, int&, int&)’:
bullet3/src/BulletDynamics/ConstraintSolver/btSequentialImpulseConstraintSolver.h:49:29: warning: ‘btSISolverSingleIterationData::m_kinematicBodyUniqueIdToSolverBodyTable’ will be initialized after [-Wreorder]
  btAlignedObjectArray<int>& m_kinematicBodyUniqueIdToSolverBodyTable;
                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
bullet3/src/BulletDynamics/ConstraintSolver/btSequentialImpulseConstraintSolver.h:44:17: warning:   ‘long unsigned int& btSISolverSingleIterationData::m_seed’ [-Wreorder]
  unsigned long& m_seed;
                 ^~~~~~
bullet3/src/BulletDynamics/ConstraintSolver/btSequentialImpulseConstraintSolver.h:57:2: warning:   when initialized here [-Wreorder]
  btSISolverSingleIterationData(btAlignedObjectArray<btSolverBody>& tmpSolverBodyPool,
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

And when I ran the executable I got an error:

```
./a.out: error while loading shared libraries: libBullet3Dynamics.so.2.88: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I attempted to add the file to my LD path:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/sam/code/bullet/bullet3/build_cmake/src/Bullet3Common/libBullet3Common.so.2.88:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

But got the same error.

It seems like I'm over-complicating this, but I can't seem to find any examples online of how to compile a program like this...

Edit:

I'm on Debian Linux.

Edit 2:

Output of ldd:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffdecb04000)
libBullet3Common.so.2.88 => /home/sam/code/bullet/bullet3/build_cmake/src/Bullet3Common/libBullet3Common.so.2.88 (0x00007fd0246e7000)
libBullet3Dynamics.so.2.88 => not found
libBullet3Geometry.so.2.88 => not found
libBullet3OpenCL_clew.so.2.88 => not found
libBulletCollision.so.2.88 => not found
libBulletDynamics.so.2.88 => not found
libBulletInverseDynamics.so.2.88 => not found
libBulletSoftBody.so.2.88 => not found
libLinearMath.so.2.88 => not found
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fd024365000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fd024061000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fd023e4a000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fd023aab000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fd024aee000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks pretty good, however `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` should be pointing to directories, not library files themselves.

So try change the LD_LIBRARY_PATH command to:

```sh
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/sam/code/bullet/bullet3/build_cmake/src/Bullet3Common/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

*after edit:*

So looking at the output from ldd, it shows that it can't find several libraries it requires.

Make sure these are all findable on your LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: Still get the same error, but thanks for the correction!

Comment: can you run the ldd command on the compiled program. e.g. ```ldd a.out```

Comment: I've added the output in the original post!

Comment: So it looks like the error wasn't exactly the same, I'm working on adding all 9 libraries to my LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to ddd4 for helping me with the export stuff. These are the commands I had to use to set the correct path for anyone who has this problem in the future:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/sam/code/bullet/bullet3/build_cmake/src/Bullet3Common:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/sam/code/bullet/bullet3/build_cmake/src/Bullet3Dynamics:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/sam/code/bullet/bullet3/build_cmake/src/Bullet3Geometry:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/sam/code/bullet/bullet3/build_cmake/src/Bullet3OpenCL:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/sam/code/bullet/bullet3/build_cmake/src/Bullet3OpenCL_clew:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/sam/code/bullet/bullet3/build_cmake/src/BulletCollision:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/sam/code/bullet/bullet3/build_cmake/src/BulletDynamics:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/sam/code/bullet/bullet3/build_cmake/src/BulletInverseDynamics:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/sam/code/bullet/bullet3/build_cmake/src/BulletSoftBody:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/sam/code/bullet/bullet3/build_cmake/src/LinearMath:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```